# Staked column chart with multiple categories grouped together in power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, dashboard

I am currently struggling to create a stacked column chart with multiple categories grouped together, that looks like stacked and clustered chart all in one chart.

I have done some research but have not gotten any result.
I created separate stacked charts as show below, there is no native way to combine them in power bi.
[image]

What I would like to achieve this chart below, where I have the 3 categories compared side by side for a given year.
[image]

Could you please help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Peter for your response,
after some research, I was able to find the below links and tweaked it for my own use case.

https://www.villezekeviking.com/how-to-combine-a-clustered-and-stacked-chart-in-power-bi/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI3eT1kRje4

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a hierarchy of 2 parameters on the x-axis, Year AND Category, but don't forget to drill down to see them both:

[image]

Comment: Dis this solve your problem or is anything still unclear?